# Monero mining speed?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, linux

Helo Everyone:

I started mining a few days ago from several of my computers (CPU).
I joined moneropool.com, my question is why sometimes when I check my stats on their website it says that I'm mining as low as 300H/s then it jumps to 6 KH/s and it's like that the entire day, how can it change so much??

The only answer I can think of, is that I'm using yam for linux and maybe I'm mining way too much for the developer?? (Using the default mining-params = xmr:av=0&donation-interval=50)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's weird. 6KH/s seems way too much for a single CPU. Which CPU is it? Did you try another pool? Could be a pool glitch.

Comment: It's not a single cpu, it's a bunch of workstations + computers, about 120 cores in total (some of them servers with 32 xeon cores).

Comment: Now we're talking :) Anyways, the culprit could be the networking part. If there's too much lag on communicating shares, or too much dropped shares, it'll have an impact on the hashrate reported by the pool. If your network had a downtime, it will cause a downward spike in pool stats. Because of this, usually the pool will report a little less "effective" hashrate than your "true" CPU hashrate.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that [node-cryptonote-pool](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool), that moneropool.com and other mining pools run on, averages your hash rate over too short a time window. If I'm reading the source code correctly, the default is 600 seconds (10 minutes).

(The reason can also be your shares are not accepted. However, that is easy to check in the output of most mining software.)

I calculate my own average of submitted work every hour instead. That produces a number that fluctuates some ±20% compared to the numbers my workers report. I run on 50 cores, + 1 GPU.

These sites have an API where you can poll your own stats. The raw numbers for your own wallet can be extracted via:

```
https://api.moneropool.com/stats_address?longpool=false&address=[WalletID]
```

It returns something like:

```
{
    "stats":{
        "hashes":"841291891",
        "lastShare":"1495972253",
        "balance":"2499455408",
        "paid":"500000000000"
    },
    "payments":[]
}
```

If you poll every hour, subtract the numbers for accepted hashes compared to last time, and divide by the difference in time, you can calculate your own numbers with a simple python script.